# How to route a button to an external site in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, react-router

Here is what I have:

```
export default function Button({
  btnLink = '',
  btnText = 'generic text',
  border = false,
}) {
  return (
    <BtnStyle border={border} className="button-wrapper">
      <Link className="button" to={btnLink}>
        {btnText}
      </Link>
    </BtnStyle>
  );
}
```

And the button itself:

```
<Button btnText="Download CV" btnLink="http://google.com" />
```

When I add a site i.e. 'google.com' to `BtnLink`, it prefixes it w/ my homepage. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Link` will append the address link to your homepage.

See more of `Link` from React Router: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

You can do this to open the address in different tab.

```
 <button
  className="button"
  onClick={() => {
    window.open(btnLink);
  }}
>
  {btnText}
</button>
```

or if you want to open the address in the same tab.

```
<button
  className="button"
  onClick={() => {
    window.location.href = btnLink
  }}
>
  {btnText}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` will not work with external links that go away from your site URL. Something such as `https://www.google.com` will not work with that component. Instead, you will need to have an `<a />` tag here and utilize the `href` attribute. You can simply style the `<a />` tag link a button to get the behavior you are looking for once it is clicked. Here is a code example using a custom `styled-component`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const LinkButtonComponent = styled.a`
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
`;

type LinkButtonProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export default function LinkButton({ children }: LinkButtonProps) {
    return (
        <LinkButtonComponent href='https://www.google.com'>
            {children}
        </LinkButtonComponent>
    );
}
```